# I am trying to put solvemedia CAPTCHA code, but it does not work

Tags: javascript, iframe, captcha

I put my challenge key and everything seems to me perfect, but when people click on the 'download track' button they go to the link without writing the security phrase in the CAPTCHA. Please help me and let me know if I need anything else. Thank you!

Here is the code:

Note: do not worry about, "your_challenge_key" I know I have to replace it.

```
<form action="http://www54.zippyshare.com/v/49820786/file.html" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="validatecaptcha">
        <h1><img src="/images/icon-disc.png"> Download Validation</h1>
        <p style="font-weight:bold; font-size:15px;">To help prevent access to the site from automated bots, we'll occasionally ask you to verify that you are human. Please complete the challenge below to access this download</p>
        <p align="center"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.solvemedia.com/papi/challenge.script?k=your_challenge_key"></script>

<noscript>
    <iframe src="http://api.solvemedia.com/papi/challenge.noscript?k=your_challenge_key" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
    <textarea name="adcopy_challenge" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="adcopy_response" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript></p>
        <div align="center"><button type="submit">Download Track</button></div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Putting together a JSFiddle would be really useful for everyone who's trying to help, if you can. It can also help you to isolate the problem by replicating it.

Comment: Thank you for replying, the problem here is that I do not even know what is a 'JSFiddle'

Comment: check this out: view-source:http://www.hiphopearly.com/download/TE1ND653